# How to fix a failing conditional statement

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

the goal is to identify an extension and output two different text files depending on whether a `.LOG` file is present or not in a directory. Here is what I have so far.

```
fp = '/home/path/to/file'

for content in fp:

  ext = os.path.splitext(content)[-1].upper() # splits root from extension

  if ext != ".LOG":

   with open(os.path.join('/home/path/to/file','Errorfile'),'w') as f:

          f.write('.LOG file not found')

  elif ext == '.LOG':

    with open(os.path.join(/home/path/to/file' ,'Correctfile') , 'w') as T:

    T.write('There is a .LOG file in directory)
```

The code just outputs the `Errorfile`and nothing past `f.write` line gets executed. My guess is its probably the way I structured my conditional statements. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'w' mode causing the file to be overwritten each time. Instead, use append mode so it adds logs to the file instead of overwriting them each time:

```
fp = '/home/path/to/file'

for content in fp:

  ext = os.path.splitext(content)[-1].upper() # splits root from extension

  if ext != ".LOG":

    with open(os.path.join('/home/path/to/file','Errorfile'),'a') as f:

        f.write('.LOG file not found\n')

  elif ext == '.LOG':

    with open(os.path.join('/home/path/to/file' ,'Correctfile') , 'a') as T:

        T.write('There is a .LOG file in directory\n')
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but  I am still having the same issue with 'a' mode. Do you think it has to do with my directory setup? or how I am utilizing the os module?